# Powershell rename files removing part starting from regex substring

Tags: regex, powershell

I struggle to write a ps code renaming bunch of excel files cutting the tails users could leave.
Simple replace does not do the thing:

```
-replace " ([vV]{1}\d{1}\.\d{1})",""
```

So I have bunch of stuff remaining.

The filenames are:

```
SomeNameSomeNameSome v1.3 written by Paul.xls

AnotherName-Another-V5.6 addendum Quarter3.xls

YetAnother.Another V3.73 updated.xls
```

All need to transform to:

```
SomeNameSomeNameSome.xls

AnotherName-Another.xls

YetAnother.Another.xls
```

So can someone help incorporating this regex     `([vV]{1}\d{1}\.\d{1})` 
which kinda works as a middle point, to remove part of the name after it and preserving the extension? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression should work for what you're asking:

```
-replace '[\s\-]v\d+\.*\d*.*(?=\.\w+$)', ''
```

## Explaining the expression

- `[\s\-]` match on either a single whitespace character or a literal `-`
- `v` match on a literal `v`
- `\d+` match on at one or more numeric characters in a row. the `+` means "match on one or more of the preceeding token
- `\.` match on a literal `.`
- `\d*` similar to `\d+`, but the `*` means to "match on zero or more of the preceeding token"
- `.` match on any character
- `()` signifies a group. Think of this as a subexpression to match on.
- `?=` Positive lookeahead. Matches a group after the main expression without including it in the result.
- `\w+` matches on one or more word characters in a row.
- `$` matches on the end of the string, or end of the line

So in plain english, the main expression comes before the `(?=)` and the match is only returned if the match comes immediately before the positive lookahead.
In this case, the positive lookahead looks for anything resembling a file extension (a literal `.` followed by any number of word chars and a line ending).

Comment: Less related to the question and more about general regular expression practice, I used to be awful with regex until a couple years ago. Check out https://regexr.com to get an excellent regex testing/learning resource. There is no option for the .NET regex engine, but .NET regex is very similar to PCRE. I have yet to find an expression (I'm sure they exist though) that doesn't work between both the .NET and PCRE engines. It also breaks down your expression and explains it token by token.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the amazing resource. This is very helpful to master this regex wizardry.

Answer (score 2):

You could use match either a whitespace char or a hyphen using a character class.

Then match the digit with an optional decimal part, the rest of the string and capture the extension in group 1.

**Note** that you can omit `{1}` from the pattern

Use the group 1 in the replacement.

```
[\s-][vV]\d+(?:\.\d+)?.*(\.xls)$
```

In parts

- `[\s-]` Match a whitespace char or `-`
- `[vV]` Match `v` or `V`
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `.*` Match 1+ times any character except a newline
- `(\.xls)` Match `.xls` or use `(\.\w+)` to match 1+ word chars
- `$` End of string

For example

```
$Strings = @("SomeNameSomeNameSome v1.3 written by Paul.xls", "AnotherName-Another-V5.6 addendum Quarter3.xls", "YetAnother.Another V3.73 updated.xls")
$Strings -replace '[\s-][vV]\d+(?:\.\d+)?.*(\.xls)$','$1'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dDtyUV/1) | [Powershell demo](https://tio.run/##TY5dC4IwGEbv@xUvIkzLDUQqCML6A1EIQmgXq72kMD@Ym9avXxkWXZ3n4hx42mZA1RUopbVuolVZ3zvYws5zkqbCA6/wn9CHLIJBlVpjDdcnHLmR7CE7JwBnXze6QDW6dNo0XbIVcCGwFqaCk@FKo4q@xRn1JLKJkEZsHYFpBdcoPp4/@/2iClvJbwgkyzt6yfr0kouFF29y9qYfs7mXj43vkoC4IbH2BQ)

Output

```
SomeNameSomeNameSome.xls
AnotherName-Another.xls
YetAnother.Another.xls
```

Comment: Note that in Powershell, the regex operators are case insensitive by default, unless you prefix the operator with `c` (e.g. `-cmatch`, `creplace`, etc)

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Thank you, I did not know that.

Comment: Yeah it's a little annoying if you don't know that, you might scratch your head figuring out how to specify the case insensitive option (or how to make it case sensitive). Another gotcha is that the `-match` operator (AFAIK) cannot do global matches, you have to use the .NET static method [`[regex]::matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8) to do a global match